# Nuxt | Vuetify themes - how to change color?

Tags: vuetify.js, nuxt.js

How can i change the global `color` attribute in Vuetify dark theme?

Like e.g.

```
html, body {
  color: red
}
```

I try to set it via variables.scss but i cant find the appropriate variable name.

Is there a variable for this or how am i supposed to change the color?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways. If you'd like to use `variables.scss` you need to enable `treeshaking` in `nuxt.config.js`

```
  vuetify: {
    customVariables: ['~/assets/variables.scss'],
    treeShake: true, // add this line
  },
```

Otherwise if you'd like to define your own colour you'd do it in the same configuration object as well. Then you can then use anywhere in your vue template.

```
  vuetify: {
    customVariables: ['~/assets/variables.scss'],
    theme: {
      themes: {
        light: {
          myawesomecolour: '#D78480', //#RRGGBB or from the colors packages
          primary: colors.blue.darken2,
          accent: colors.grey.darken3,
          secondary: colors.amber.darken3,
          info: colors.teal.lighten1,
          warning: colors.amber.base,
          error: colors.deepOrange.accent4,
          success: colors.green.accent3
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

Or in `layouts/default.vue` insert a style tag and put in your custom css

```
<style>
  html, body {
    color: red;
  }
</style>
```